# Unable to center text with the C# lib ClosedXML

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to center text with the MVC lib ClosedXML but it only works when the cell has a background color set and I want to set the alignment without it:

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook("c:\\temp\\file.xlsx");
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheet("Sheet");

worksheet .Cell(1, 1).Style.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.White; // without this line it doe not work
worksheet.Cell(1, 1).Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
```

Answer (score 16):

This works for me:

```
worksheet.Cell(1, 1).Style.Alignment.SetHorizontal(XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center);
```

but as far as I know it's just a wrapper around `...Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center`

Answer (score 3):

The [solution provided by mcalex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55532734/10871073) works well for a particular cell. However, if you want to center align whole worksheet, you can use the following code:

```
ws.Style.Alignment.SetHorizontal(XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center);
```

Answer (score 1):

ws.Cell(row, Column).Value = "Alignment top";
ws.Style.Alignment.SetVertical(XLAlignmentVerticalValues.Top)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).